# Python3 pathlib's Path.glob() generator keeps increasing memory usage when performed on large file structure

Tags: python-3.x, memory, pathlib

I used `pathlib's Path(<path>).glob()` function for walking through file directories and grabbing their files' name and extension parameters. My Python script is meant to run on a large file system, so I tested it on my root directory of my Linux machine. When left for a few hours I noticed that my machine's memory usage increased by over a GB.

After using memray and memory_profiler, I found that whenever I looped through directory items using the generator the memory usage kept climbing.

Here's the problematic code (path is the path to the root directory):

```py
dir_items = Path(path).glob("**/*")

for item in dir_items:
    pass
```

Since I was using a generator, my expectation was that my memory requirements would remain constant throughout. I think I might have some fundamental misunderstanding. Can anyone explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows. `glob` search has a high memory usage, which does not seem to be attributed to the Python process. In Windows tasks manager, I see growing memory usage and number of threads, which decrease only slowly after the glob search is done and even after python process exits. No clue why this happens and how to solve it.

Comment: May be related: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/102613